# Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $S(n)S(n + 2) = 2022$, where $S(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I was doing my math homework and I came across this problem:

> Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $S(n)S(n + 2) = 2022$, where $S(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$.

I tried letting $S(n)=2022,$ and this is what I got:

$S(n)=2022,$ Thus $S(n+2)=1 \Rightarrow n+2=10^k.$

And $n=10^k-2 \Rightarrow S(n)=9k-1 \Rightarrow 9k=2023.$

But then $k$ is not a natural number so I don't know what to do now. Can I have help? Thanks!

Comment: You are solving one case only. It seems in this case you get no solutions. There're more cases to consider. Try S(n) to be some other divisor of 2022.

Comment: Cases like what? I can't think of any :(

Comment: Well, you assume S(n)=2022, you didn't derive this. So you should try S(n) to be some other divisor of 2022.

Comment: Since $2022=337\cdot 6$ and $6\equiv 337+2\mod 9$, try to take $n$ such that $S(n)=337$ and $S(n+2)=6$.

Comment: There are only four factorizations of $2022$ into two factors:  $1 \cdot 2022$, $2 \cdot 1011$, $6 \cdot 337$, and $3 \cdot 674$.  That limits your search a lot.

Comment: $n = 5\cdot 10^{37}-1$ seems to work but I don't know if it's the smallest.

Comment: ugh...it doesn't work, never mind. Here is my false reasoning:

$S(n)=1011; S(n+2)=2  \Rightarrow n+2=10^k+1  \Rightarrow n=10^k-1  \Rightarrow S(n)=9k-1  \Rightarrow 9k-1=1011  \Rightarrow k=\frac{1012}{9}.$

Which doesn't work, humph :(

Comment: @PeterPhipps How did you get that result?

Comment: I assumed the two sums of digits would be $337$ and $6$. For two values differing by $2$ to have such a gap between their sums of digits, one would have to be just under a power of $10$ and the other just over. The digits of $10^{37}-1$ sum to $333$ but those of $10^{37}+1$ only make $2$, so I needed to add a bit. Trial and error brought me to $5\cdot 10^{37}-1$ ($49999999999999999999999999999999999999$, sum of digits $337$) and $5\cdot 10^{37}+1$ ($50000000000000000000000000000000000001$, sum of digits $6$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

As mentioned above, there are only four factorizations of 2022 into two factors:

- $1 \cdot 2022$
- $2 \cdot 1011$
- $3 \cdot 674$
- $6 \cdot 337$.

That limits your search a lot.

We can eliminate the first case ($1 \cdot 2022$) as follows:

For the sum of digits to be $1$, the number $n$ must be $1, 10, 100$, $\ldots$, that is, $n = 10^k$ (or $n-2 = 10^k$) for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \geq 0$.

That means the other factor must have the sum of its digits be 2022.  There are two cases here, either the other number is a) $10^k + 2$ or b) $10^k - 2$ (according to the problem statement).  Case a) will always have the sum of digits as $3$, and hence cannot solve the problem.

Case b) admits numbers of the form $8$, $98$, $998$, $\ldots$.  The sum of such digits is $9 r + 8$, where $r = k-2$ is an integer.  But $9 r + 8$ can never equal 2022.  (Easy to check.)  So case b) cannot solve the problem.

Hence we can eliminate the $1 \cdot 2022$ cases.

We can thus limit our search to cases where one of the numbers has a sum of digits equal 2, or 3 or 6.

We can also eliminate the second case ($2 \cdot 1011$) as follows:

This is a vast reduction in the search space.  Consider the sum of digits = 2.  Either the number is $2 \cdot 10^k$ or $10^{r_1} + 10^{r_2}$ for $\{ r_1, r_2 \} \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Here too, we know that the other number cannot be of the form $10^{r_1} + 10^{r_2} + 2$, as its sum of digits will always be $4$ (for $r_2 \neq 0$).

Thus we need search $10^{r_1} + 10^{r_2} - 2$ for sum of digits = 1011.  All numbers of this form have sum of digit = $9 k$.  (Easy to check.). But $9 k \neq 1011$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  So we can eliminate the second major case, above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome.  I know I *helped*, but I didn't *solve* the full problem (yet).  So thanks for the accept!

Comment: I just eliminated the third case